# undefined method `amount' for nil:NilClass with Payola

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, payola

I've been following this tutorial for [Payola](https://github.com/payolapayments/payola/wiki/Subscriptions).

I've tested adding my own plans and they do appear on my dashboard and on my console. However, when I go to create a subscription, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `amount' for nil:NilClass
```

on the following line:

```
subscription = Payola::CreateSubscription.call(params, owner)
```

Here are my files for reference:

subscriptions/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Subscription</h1>
<em><%= @plan.name %><em/><br><br>

<!-- this header can go in <head> or at the bottom of <body> -->
<%= render 'payola/transactions/stripe_header' %>

<%= form_tag('/subscriptions', class: 'payola-onestep-subscription-form', 'data-payola-base-path' => '/payola', 'data-payola-plan-type' => @plan.plan_class, 'data-payola-plan-id' => @plan.id) do |f| %>
  <span class="payola-payment-error"></span>
  <input name="stripeEmail" data-payola="email" type="hidden" value="<%= current_user.email %>"/>
  Card Number<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="number"></input><br><br>
  Exp Month<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="exp_month"></input><br><br>
  Exp Year<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="exp_year"></input><br><br>
  CVC<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="cvc"></input><br><br>
  <input type="submit"></input>
<% end %>
```

subscriptions_controller.erb

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  # bring in the `render_payola_status` helper.
  include Payola::StatusBehavior

  before_action :load_plans

  def index
  end 

  def new
    @plan = EmojiPlan.find(params[:plan_id])
  end

  def create
    # do any required setup here, including finding or creating the owner object
    owner = current_user # this is just an example for Devise

    # set your plan in the params hash
    params[:plan] = EmojiPlan.find_by(id: params[:plan_id])

    # call Payola::CreateSubscription
    subscription = Payola::CreateSubscription.call(params, owner)

    # Render the status json that Payola's javascript expects
    render_payola_status(subscription)
  end

  protected

  def load_plans
    @plans = EmojiPlan.order('amount')
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :emoji_plans
resources :subscriptions
devise_for :admins
devise_for :users
mount Payola::Engine => '/payola', as: :payola
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

emoji_plan.rb

```
class EmojiPlan < ApplicationRecord
include Payola::Plan

def redirect_path(subscription)
    # you can return any path here, possibly referencing the given subscription
    '/'
end
end
```

create_emoji_plans.rb

```
class CreateEmojiPlans < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :emoji_plans do |t|
      t.integer :amount
      t.string :interval
      t.string :stripe_id
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Don't make fun of my plan names - I'm making a 'fun' project. ;)

Comment: can u show the migration file for EmojiPlan?

Comment: Edited the post to include the migration file.

Comment: that's weird, seems like your params are missing data, you should print your params before this line `subscription = Payola::CreateSubscription.call(params, owner)`

Comment: can you show the entire backtrace?

Comment: Most likely this happens because Payola can't find the plan from the params. Can you check what's in params[:plan_id] and is this a valid plan id?

Comment: Changing the params line to params[:plan] = EmojiPlan.find_by(params[:plan_id]) rendered this: {"guid":"j3u71g","status":"pending","error":null}

Is this what is expected?

Comment: I'm running into this exact same problem. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @acoustic_north I did not.

Comment: @Edie W, I submitted a question here and got an answer that helped me figure out what I was doing wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389223/payola-issue-undefined-method-amount-for-nilnilclass/