# Payola issue: undefined method `amount' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payola

I'm just learning how to use Payola to create Subscriptions for my RoR 5.1.5 test app. I'm following along with the instructions on the wiki.

I've set up the sample form taken from the example on the Wiki and dropped it right into app/views/subscriptions/new.html.erb. When I enter the credit card, email, expiration date and click Submit, I get this Rails error: undefined method `amount' for nil:NilClass

I've created the SubscriptionPlan in the rails console and confirmed it exists.
I've confirmed that the new Plan shows up in my Stripe dashboard after creating it in the console.

I'm sure I've overlooked something, and hoping someone has experienced this same issue and can point me in the right direction. It feels like I am not specifying the plan anywhere. I'm not sure how I should do that.

Thanks for your help.

Code is here.
app/models/subscription_plan.rb

```
class SubscriptionPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Payola::Plan
end
```

/app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  # bring in the `render_payola_status` helper.
  include Payola::StatusBehavior

  def new
    @plan = SubscriptionPlan.first
  end

  def create
    # do any required setup here, including finding or creating the owner object
    owner = current_user # this is just an example for Devise

    # set your plan in the params hash
    params[:plan] = SubscriptionPlan.find_by(id: params[:plan_id])

    # call Payola::CreateSubscription
    subscription = Payola::CreateSubscription.call(params, owner)

    # Render the status json that Payola's javascript expects
    render_payola_status(subscription)
  end
end
```

/app/views/subscriptions/new.html.erb

```
 <!-- this header can go in <head> or at the bottom of <body> -->
<%= render 'payola/transactions/stripe_header' %>

<%= form_tag('/subscriptions',
      class: 'payola-onestep-subscription-form',
      'data-payola-base-path' => '/payola',
      'data-payola-plan-type' => @plan.plan_class,
      'data-payola-plan-id' => @plan.id
  ) do |f| %>
  <span class="payola-payment-error"></span>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="email" name="stripeEmail" data-payola="email"></input><br>
  Card Number<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="number"></input><br>
  Exp Month<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="exp_month"></input><br>
  Exp Year<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="exp_year"></input><br>
  CVC<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="cvc"></input><br>
  <input type="submit"></input>
<% end %>
```

/app/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: "pages#index"
  resources :subscriptions
  get 'pages/index'

  get 'pages/donate'

  mount Payola::Engine => '/payola', as: :payola
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: A stack trace / caller stack would be helpful. Without knowing **where** the error occurs there is not much we can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `create` action, you mention the `SubscriptionPlan`'s id like so

```
# set your plan in the params hash
params[:plan] = SubscriptionPlan.find_by(id: params[:plan_id])
```

From your form in the view, I cannot see that you will submit a param called `:plan_id`. Perhaps post your params from the log file, to make sure the plan's id is there. Otherwise you have to tweak the form to include the plan's id. The plan will be present in the form as `@plan`, so you could include a hidden field:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:plan_id, @plan.id) %>
```

Then the plan should be found. Your `NoMethodError for nil` with the method `amount` points to the problem, that the `plan` that the `amount` method is sent to, is `nil`. (At least that's my guess)

Comment: Thank you. You pointed me in the right direction. I had to add the hidden field tag as you showed above, but I manually added the integer for the plan.id of the plan i created earlier. I don't have a complete site where there are products with variables that I could use to populate the @plan.id variable at this time. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Cool! Always happy to help.